# Why is this switch deleting an extra line (PowerShell)

Tags: regex, powershell

This code is supposed to find a line with a regular expression and replace the line with "test". It is finding that line and replace it with "test" but also deleting the line under it, no matter what is in the next line down. I feel like I am just missing something about how a switch works in PowerShell.

Note: This is super boiled down code. There is a larger program this is part of.

```
$reg = '^HI\*BH'
$appendText = '' 
$file   = Get-ChildItem (join-path $PSScriptRoot "a.txt.BAK")

foreach ($f in $file){

  switch -regex -file $f {

    $reg
    {
     
     $appendText = "test"
     
    }
    default {

      If ($appendText -eq '') {$appendText = $_}
      $appendText
      $appendText = ''
    }
  }
  
}
```

a.txt.BAK

```
HI*BH>00>D8>0*BH>00>D8>0*BH>A1>D8>0*BH>B1>D8>0000000~
HI*BE>02>>>0.00*BE>00>>>0.00~
NM1*71*1*TTT*NAME****XX*0000000~
PRV*AT*PXC*000V00000X~
```

Output:

```
test
NM1*71*1*TTT*NAME****XX*0000000~
PRV*AT*PXC*000V00000X~
```

Comment: Following the logic of what you're trying to do and why is difficult.  That's usually an indicator the approach is wrong.  In your place, I'd rethink my approach.

Comment: It doesn't "delete" anything - you _overwrite_ the existing value of `$appendText` (from the previous iteration) without ever outputting it

Answer (score 1):

The switch is not "deleting" anything - but you explicit ask it to overwrite `$appendText` on match, and you only ever output (and reset the value of) `$appendText` when it *doesn't*.

> This code is supposed to find a line with a regular expression and replace the line with "test".

In that case I suggest you simplify your `switch`:

```
switch -regex -file $f {
    $reg {
        "test"
    }
    default {
        $_
    }
}
```

That's it - no fiddling around with variables - just output "test" on match, otherwise output the line as-is.

---

If you insist on using the intermediate variable, you'll need to output + reset the value in both cases:

```
switch -regex -file $f {
    $reg {
        $appendText = "test"
        $appendText
        $appendText = ''
    }
    default {
        $appendText = $_
        $appendText
        $appendText = ''
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the program like this because its actually a much larger program that i boiled down to the issue. it is like that for a reason

Comment: @ryankennedy712 I'm afraid I can't read minds :-) I've update my answer

Comment: The simple option should be all that’s required even if it’s partial text replacement. +1 for the clean and simple example.